# OpenGL ES - set the width, height, depth of an object in 3D

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

I would like to ask about OPENGL ES android, I want to build a wall with specific width, height, and depth

```
public void buildingW(float width, float height, float depth)
```

in order to place into my program, anyone can suggest me the ideas how to do this ?

Is there anyway to build one obj file then read it ? or we can draw it directly?

Thank you  very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most easy would be to simply use a cube and scale it as `glScalef(width, height, depth)` this would be optimal as even if you draw multiple different walls you need only one vertex buffer.

Another pretty good way would be simply creating the vertices in load time predefining dimensions (web is filled with sources for that). In this case each wall will have its own vertex buffer but you don't need to scale it.

As for using an obj file you would have to import the cube and use scale to transform it so it is pretty much the same as the first solution but you can not use it with the second solution (though importing a simple cube obj seems a waste).

You could draw it directly using a fragment shader with only width, height, depth and some centre point but you will need quite a few math skills and it would be much slower then using vertices so I do not suggest it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. as im quite new to opengl es, can I just create an array of vertices, then use the function glDrawArrays in order to draw the wall ? Thank you

Comment: Or as I already had 6 cubes which surrounds the center, i wish to adjust the width, height, and depth of them in order to create 6 walls. Can I do that way? Thank you

Comment: Any of the ways you wrote are good. Try using your cube, position it to where you wish the wall centre is, then use glScale to set the dimensions.